# Restricting user to see only one page and hide all others pages in the entire oracle apex application?

Tags: oracle-apex-5, oracle-ebs, oracle-apex-5.1

Can we restrict a user to view and use only one page and hide all other pages in the apex application in oracle apex 5?
The scenario is similar as we assign a particular responsibility to a particular user in Oracle EBS and he has the access to use that particular responsibility and rest are hidden to view.
How to achieve this??

Answer (score 0):

Yes ,You can do it by using authorization schemes.

By using authorization scheme ,you can restrict the user for viewing other pages.

Regards,
Nikita

Comment: Thanks For the reply can let me know the steps of hiding the pages from the other users.

Answer (score 0):

Easiest way is to create an Access Control page. It will automatically create three authorization schemes for you. Admin, Edit, and View. You can assign users to those. Set application mode to `Public read only. Edit and administrative privileges controlled by access control list.` This will open the application for all the users, except for the pages that you control using authorization schemes.